# How to retrieve data related to any company in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I have added a custom field into PreferencesGeneral called UsrShortCompanyName. I need a static method which should return a Dictionary where Key == Company.CompanyKey and Value == PreferencesGeneral.UsrShortCompanyName. 
So, I need Acumatica's ORM to perform an sql query which should look like:

```
select c.CompanyKey, p.UsrCompanyShortName from Company c inner join PreferencesGeneral p on p.CompanyID = c.CompanyID where c.CompanyType != 'System'
```

I have a few questions:

1. PXSelect perform queries in scope of current company so it will
   automatically add condition "WHERE CompanyID = <CurrentCompanyId>".
   Is it possible to prevent ORM from adding this company restriction?
2. Neither PreferencesGeneral nor Company DAC contain CompanyID
   field, so I'm not able to write something like

> PXSelectJoin<PX.Objects.GL.Company, InnerJoin<PreferencesGeneral,
>   On<PX.Objects.GL.Company.companyId,
>   Equal<PreferencesGeneral.companyId>>>>

What should I do in such cases?

3. Is there any possibility to execute plain SQL using
   Acumatica's ORM? The only similar function I have found is
   PXDatabase.Execute method but it can be used only with stored
   procedures and it will return data only if SP has OUTPUT parameters.
   But in my case it is not an option as OUTPUT parameter can't be of
   TABLE type.

The only workaround I have found is to perform my sql query in scope of new SqlConnection, but in this case I need to get the same connection string as for Acumatica's ORM. I wonder how Acumatica determines whether it should search for connection string in Web.config(in case it's local or QA server) or in Azure Configuration(for Production).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The isolation of companies is strongly enforced by BQL, and you won't be able to retrieve data from another company unless you're logged into this company. The ORM also takes care of returning you the data from other company IDs if this data is split/shared with another company. As you have noticed, for tables that don't contain a CompanyID field, the system returns all the data contained in this table.

You are also not allowed to run direct SQL queries unless you go through a stored procedure, and you won't be able to open a SqlConnection unless you modify the default security policy (SqlClientPermission inside web_project_x.config). Allowing direct SQL queries could potentially make the application vulnerable to SQL injection, and also makes the data of other companies 'permeable' -- although most installations use a separate database for each registered customer, Acumatica is also used in fully multi-tenant environments, and we need to ensure there is proper isolation between the tenants (customers).

If you are developing an ISV solution that is intended for multiple Acumatica customers, I would strongly advise that you avoid techniques to bypass the ORM. Such solutions will not be certified by Acumatica and I consider them suitable only for one-off customizations. Instead, you can use one of the following ways to get to your data:

- Create a special table without a CompanyID which would store data available to all companies
- Use web services to connect to other companies
- Use a PXLoginScope block to temporarily run code under the identify of another user in another company
- Create a SQL View that is bound to a BQL table of the same name
- Call a SQL stored procedure which aggregates data from multiple companies (and omit the CompanyID field in the resulting view)

Another argument for sticking with BQL is that your code will work transparently on MySQL and SQL Server. If you rely on a SQL view or stored procedure, you will have to create different versions to support both platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Though SQL-injection isn't a problem in my case, I realise all drawback of my solution. I thought of almost every option you provided but they are not suitable for me for different reasons. The only option I didn't try/think of is an SQL View. I'll try and it now. 
One more question: is it possible to call an SQL table-valued function using BQL and assign the result of the function to a variable?
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I've never seen an example of a table-valued function being called. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is a CompanyKey column in Company table. I have added UrsCompanyShortName into PreferencesGeneral table. I need a way to get a dictionary where CompanyKey is key and UrsCompanyShortName value. So, this data can be represented as a table with two columns(it can be done by sql view or sql function). In case of a view I need an additional DAC in order to be able to retrieve data from the view, in case of function I could have just called it and assign it's return value to some IEnumerable variable. Function can be a bit more convinient variant than view in some cases, but view is ok as well